# Problems with BibLaTeX and origyear in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, datetime

This is my first time posting a question here so please excuse some mistakes. What I want to do is to cite something with its original publication year and have it appear as such in my bibliography. I am using BibLaTeX with the following options:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, bibstyle=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
```

To get my citation label to show the `origyear` I was happy to find the following solution:

```
\DeclareLabelyear{\field{origyear}\field{year}}
```

This gives me the original publication date in citations, if available. Sadly, the bibliography does not include this label, but the `year` field, so that I cite "lastname (1891) and my bibliography has an entry much like

```
lastname, first (2002): titel...
```

for example. To accommodate for this I did the following:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\iffieldundef{origyear}{%
  \printnames{author} (\printdate)\addcolon\addspace
  }{%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printtext[]{\printnames{author} (\printorigdate)\addcolon\addspace}%
  }%
\clearname{author}%
\clearfield{year}}
```

So, now I have the right label, meaning my bibliography entry is

```
lastname, firstname (1981): titel...
```

but the actual publication date is lost. I would like something like

```
lastname, firstname (1981): titel... published in booktitel (or whatever) 2002..."
```

Two questions come to mind here:

- is there an easier way to get to where I am at, that is why does the `\DeclareLabelyear` not change the label in my bibliography, too?
- how do I include the actual publication date in my bibliography as well, and where?

(Perhaps a third question would also make sense at this point:

- does the citation style I have in mind make any sense in the first place, or should I just go with something like the APA suggests and have a (1981/2002) label in citations and my bibliography?)

EDIT: I was told to include a minimum working example, so here it comes (hopefully sufficient):

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    bibstyle=authoryear-comp,
     ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
{\textsc{#1}%
\ifblank{#3}{}{\addcomma\space \textsc{#3}}}
{\ifblank{#3}{}{\textsc{#3}\space}%
\textsc{#1}}%
\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
{\addcomma\space}
{}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
\iffieldundef{origyear}{%
  \printnames{author} (\printdate)\addcolon\addspace
  }{%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printtext[]{\printnames{author} (\printorigdate)\addcolon\addspace}%
  }%
\clearname{author}%
\clearfield{year}}

\DeclareLabelyear{\field{origyear}\field{year}}

\begin{document}

 Some text \cite{Frege.2002a}, some text \cite{Frege.2002b}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is everything (as far as I see) that may have to do with my problem. Of course, here is my `.bib` entry:

```
ï»¿@incollection{Frege.2002c,
 author = {Frege, Gottlob},
 title = {{\"U}ber Sinn und Bedeutung},
 pages = {23--46},
 bookpaginationtype = {page},
 volume = {4},
 publisher = {Vandenhoeck {\&} Ruprecht},
 isbn = {978-3-525-30603-1},
 series = {Sammlung Philosophie},
 editor = {Textor, Mark},
 booktitle = {Funktion - Begriff - Bedeutung},
 year = {2002},
 origdate = {1892},
 location = {G{\"o}ttingen},
 number = {4}
}


@incollection{Frege.2002b,
 author = {Frege, Gottlob},
 title = {Funktion und Begriff},
 pages = {2--22},
 bookpaginationtype = {page},
 volume = {4},
 publisher = {Vandenhoeck {\&} Ruprecht},
 isbn = {978-3-525-30603-1},
 series = {Sammlung Philosophie},
 editor = {Textor, Mark},
 booktitle = {Funktion - Begriff - Bedeutung},
 year = {2002},
 origdate = {1891},
 location = {G{\"o}ttingen},
 number = {4}
}
```

Additionally you can see from this that this problem concerns an `@incollection`entry, but I would like to fix it generally.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to help you with the code, but re your question on whether the citation style makes sense, my answer would be that perhaps it doesn't. Have you looked at the biblatex-chicago package? I use this package, which allows you to cite references using both the origdate and the date, or only the origdate (which is not encouraged by the Chicago Manual of Style).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the standard author-year styles use the `authoryear` bibliography style, which has an additional option called `mergedate`. Its various settings are explained in example 50 of the biblatex documentation. To use `labelyear` in place of `year` in the bibliography ditch your `\AtEveryBibitem` hook and just load biblatex with one of the following:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp,mergedate=basic]{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp,mergedate=minimum]{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp,mergedate=false]{biblatex}
```

Alternatively you can redefine the `date+extrayear` bibliography macro:

```
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}
```

The next release will include some improvements to `mergedate` so that the author-year styles make consistent use of `labelyear` and year labels can be defined with greater flexibility via `\DeclareLabeldate`.

Comment: Ok wow. That just solved all my problems to my liking in a very elegant way. I wasnt aware of the `mergedate` option. (The package documentation is a bit overwhelming.)